# AS3 javascript callback issue in chrome

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, google-chrome

I'm making a callback from javascript to a method on my swf. It works in Firefox with no problems, but in chrome the second parameter that's passed is always received as null?

I've debugged my javascript and found that everything is working fine and the two values that are passed to the swf are correct at the point where the callback to the swf is made.

At first i thought this might be a cross domain issue, but have ruled that out as if it were the case then the method on swf would just not be called at all. The second value is a binary string representation of an image and the length of the string that is passed is 101601, so i'm wondering whether there's possibly a limitation on the amount of data that can be passed? The first parameter is a much smaller string representing the file type and this always gets received successfully.

Like i said, the strange thing is, it works perfectly fine in Firefox?

**NOTE** - so i've just tried it with a much smaller image (stupidly it hadn't occurred to me to test that until i wrote this), where the string length is only 133 and it still fails. So that rules that out.

I've also checked the AS3 docs and it doesn't appear to mention any such limitation.

The string is being produced using the FileReader class's readAsBinaryString() method. As far as i'm aware this outputs a UTF 16 string representation of the binary it receives. Although i think i'm right in thinking that this shouldn't be an issue, as it's still just a string and the encoding only really affects the decoding?

Javascript

```
var readFile = function(file)
{
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onloadend = function( evt )
    {
        alert( reader.result.length );//this outputs the correct length
        alert( reader.result ); //this outputs the binary encoded as a String

        swf.addImage( file.type, reader.result );
    }

    reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
}
```

AS3

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback( "addImage", addImageHandler );
```

and

```
private function addImageHandler( type:String, file:String ):void
{
    trace( "type: ", type );//this traces the type correctly
    trace( "file: ", file );//this traces out null in chrome, but traces the binary string in firefox
}
```

Comment: You might get an answer faster if you include some code. Hope you find a solution.

Comment: I've answered the question below

Answer (score 1):

So there appears to be an issue with passing the UTF-16 encoded string from javascript to flash, but only in chrome?

I'm not sure why this would be the case, but if i encode the UTF-16 string to base46, or convert it from UTF-16 to UTF-8 within the Javascript, before i pass it to the swf, then everything works as expected.

**EDIT**

On further testing, the solution turned out to be simpler than expected, it was just a case of calling encodeURI on the UTF-16 string and then calling decodeURI at the other end.

Javascript

```
var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onloadend = function( evt )
{   
    swf.addImage( file.type, encodeURI( reader.result ) );
}

reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
```

AS3

```
private function dropHandler( type:String, file:String ):void
{
    file = decodeURI( file );
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course without a code sample from you this might not help at all, but in case it could:

This is how I invoke a JS function from AS3 with say 2 parameters:

```
ExternalInterface.call("JavaScriptFunctionName", arg1_value, arg2_value);
```

Where this is the JS function:

```
function JavaScriptFunctionName(arg1, arg2) { ...
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't think the problem is with the way that the callback is being added as it works fine in Firefox, it's just that it doesn't seem to work in Chrome?